# Given three non-negative numbers $x,y,z$ so that $x+y+z=100$ and $x,y,z\notin (\!33,34\!)$. Prove that $xyz\leqq 33\cdot 34\cdot 33$ .

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, karamata-inequality

Given three non-negative numbers $x, y, z$ so that $x+ y+ z= 100$ and $x, y, z\notin (\!33, 34\!)$. Prove that
$$xyz\leqq 33\cdot 34\cdot 33$$
I want to see another solution that is not as same as the following one due to one Vietnamese student

Wlog $x\geqq y\geqq z$ then $x\geqq 34$ and $z\leqq 33$, from am-gm inequality
$$\frac{x}{34}\frac{y}{33}\frac{z}{33}\leqq \left ( \frac{\frac{x}{34}+ \frac{y}{33}+ \frac{z}{33}}{3} \right )^{3}= \left ( \frac{34(x+ y+ z)- x}{3\cdot 34\cdot 33} \right )^{3}\leqq 1$$
so $xyz\leqq 33\cdot 34\cdot 33$. I took the source from DOTOANNANG(@HaiDangel). I hope you like it, thanks

Comment: Are we talking about integers here?

Comment: "integers" is the original one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $x\geq34$ and $z\leq33$ and since $$x+y=100-z\geq100-33=34+33,$$ we obtain $$(x,y,z)\succ(34,33,33)$$

and since $f(x)=e^x$ increases and $\ln$ is a concave function, by Karamata we obtain:
$$xyz=e^{\ln{x}+\ln{y}+\ln{z}}\leq e^{\ln34+\ln33+\ln33}=34\cdot33^2$$ and we are done!

Comment: $x, y, z\notin (\!33, 34\!)$

Comment: copy that , SIR

Comment: @MYPRETTIESTGIRL I fixed. See now.

Comment: that's all i want to see ∞ what style !